# How to secure a connection to PHP MySQL service

Tags: php, android, mysql, security

I need a method to secure my application which is making an HTTP request to a PHP file on my server which communicates with MySQL to get and set data.

I need a way to secure this, so that other people cannot call the PHP and communicate with the database.

What worries me is the fact that people can see the URL with a packet sniffer. Is there any way to hide this?

The answers I found use keys and stuff, but it is still not secure because if some one uses a packet sniffer to watch the parameters he can fake call the PHP later with the keys and the URL.

Comment: This question is pretty hard to follow. It would help if you used capital letters and a spell checker.

Comment: If you use SSL for communication a sniffer won't be a problem.

Comment: Okay i will try to explain my problem better:
I communicate with the android to php. i send a parameters in the post like url of the php, data of the server (like mysql admin password, database name and etc)
I want to hide this information from people who may use sniffer, so they will not find out this sensitive data - the database password, the php url (becouse then they can build their own sql statements and destroy my database)... 
any suggestions? thx guys!

Comment: By the way use MCrypt to encrypt the sensitive data i send in the post... althought im not sure it is very secure becouse if some one will decompile my android program they may find this key for the mcrypt... anyway... lets focus on the first problem now: how do i communicate securly between the android and the php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be overly simplistic answer, but couldn't you use SSL to encrypt the connection, and POST the keys?

This way the POST data would not be visible to a sniffer, and 'outsiders' cannot make meaningful requests that will actually be processed by your script if they did know the URL.

I believe this is exactly how the twitter API works..

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
does ssl will make people not to see the parameters is send in the post? ty

Comment: Only the application and the server can see the message contents

Comment: okey thank you very much about your help, can you give me a link for a secure code of ssl? i searched this and watched some codes but everytime people comment there that the way the code is writted is not really secure...
And what do you mean by 'Post the keys'? 
btw i writted up on the comments that i post a very sensitive data like the sql login information - database name + password... does by using ssl this data will be secure? or there is an other way to pass this data with a secure... 
thank you :)

Comment: You don't use code exactly to do SSL, you would enable it on the web hosting, and then you need a certificate (not too expensive these days) that you can get from many places online, I believe even goDaddy.

Then you have your app post to "https://" instead of "http://"

Also, I would suggest not actually having the database info being posted from the app. Instead, put (i assume) php file on your server with the info, and have the included in other php files that need to connect to the database). That way, if you post, the server will get the variables from on the server instead.

Comment: okey i did everything, purchased an ssl and installed it, i got now https url to my webservice.
just one q: how do i secure the password file in the server? where should i store it? @DarrylJackman

Comment: I doesn't matter too much. I usually have a folder for example "includes", and put files that regularly is included in other files. I always put a "index.html" (for all subfolders) which is blank, this stops servers from displaying the directory contents if someone navigated there If you are more cautious you can also play with permissions also. This is fairly secure because the password is not actually transmitted across the internet, and because no one remotely can view it, then only the php parser which is on the actual server 'sees' it and sends to the mysql engine which again is local.